# JavaScript Either BOF or EOF is True

Tags: javascript, sql, ms-access

I receive the following error on my web page when retrieveing out of MS access.

> Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record

I am able to retrieve all the records with the query, but think i am not checking when i reach the end of the file. not quite sure how to do that.
here is my JS code:

```
var fieldcount = adoRS.Fields.Count;
if(!adoRS.bof) {
adoRS.MoveFirst();
while(!adoRS.eof) 
{
for (var y=0;y < fieldcount;y++)
{
document.write("<p>" + adoRS.fields(2).value + "| " + adoRS.fields(3).value + "| " + adoRS.fields(4).value + "| " + adoRS.fields(5).value + "| " + adoRS.fields(6).value + "| " + adoRS.fields(7).value + "| ");
adoRS.MoveNext();
    }
}
}

else { document.write("No data found for today."); };


adoRS.Close();
adoRS = null;
adoconn.Close();
adoconn = null;
}
```

Comment: @Remou Remou, you had assisted in the past, not sure if you can take a look?

Comment: What do you mean that you can retrieve all records with the query? Do other queries against this database work and just this one is failing? It seems to me it's either an issue with the connection string (maybe add that to your code post), or the BOF/EOF checks. Try removing those and just try writing one field for simplicity's sake, just to see if it's reading the database. After the MoveFirst, just write one field with "document.write(ado.fields(2).value". If this writes successfully, then you know you're connected to the database and writing, but if this fails, then there's a conn issue.

Comment: @James Toomey The query works fine. it retrieves all records perfectly. however, when the page stops loading, i see an error on the "lower-left" of my web page. when i double click it, i see that BOF or EOF error. not sure how to fix that. think its got to do something with my syntax. this error is driving me nuts :( please help

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself. just removed the FOR statement and it worked fine. 
thanks for taking time out and looking at my questions. cheers.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. The fieldcount variable stores the number of columns, not the number of records. When you loop over fieldcount and do a movenext inside that loop, you're moving beyond the record limit. For ex, if the table has 10 columns but only 3 records, the for loop will repeat 10 times and try to call MoveNext 10 times, moving past the end of the recordset. The while(!adoRS.eof) doesn't protect you in this case because it won't even have reached the end of the code block and returned to the beginning to check for EOF again.